# Java GUI Action Event to change layout

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to solve a problem where I have some buttons and a bottom panel "FlowLayout", "BorderLayout", "GridLayout" to switch layout of the buttons which are at top. So far I did this but it is not working. Need a solution please.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;

class Calculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

Container container;

JPanel p = new JPanel();
JPanel panelTop = new JPanel();
JButton b[] = new JButton[12];
JButton layoutButton[] = new JButton[3];
String sLayout[] = {"FlowLayout", "BorderLayout", "GridLayout"};
String s[] = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "11",    "12"};
String Screen = "";

public Calculator() {
    super("Calculator");
    container = getContentPane();
    for (int i = 0; i < sLayout.length; i++) {
        layoutButton[i] = new JButton(sLayout[i]);
        layoutButton[i].addActionListener(this);
        p.add(layoutButton[i]);
    }
    container.add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

}//End Constructor

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    if (event.getSource() == layoutButton[2]) {
        panelTop.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4, 5, 5));
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            b[i] = new JButton("Button " + s[i]);

            panelTop.add(b[i]);
        }

        container.add(panelTop, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
    calculator.setSize(500, 500);
    calculator.setVisible(true);
    calculator.setResizable(true);
    calculator.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    calculator.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   }
}//end class
```

If i can make it work for one button I belief I can sort out for the rest.

Comment: Call revalidate and repaint on the container you've update

Comment: one problem. If I keep use a button it keeps re-add buttons on the top panel which I don't want. how to solve that?

Comment: `panelTop.removeAll`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer, Why do you always give answers in comments? Giving the correct answer in the _place it belongs_ would only increase your reputation.

Comment: @Hackerdarshi Because 1- it's a one liner; 2- The op should have referenced the JavaDocs and tutorials first; 3- I really don't need the rep that badly (at least not from such simple questions)

Comment: @MadProgrammer That's what great people do! :)

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to remember when dealing with Swing layouts is, they are lazy.  This might seem like a bad thing at first, but when you start adding/removing dozens of components, you can to realise that you don't actually want the layout to be validated until you're finished ALL the updates.

Validating a container hierarchy is not a trivial thing, so the less you have to do it, the better.

Basically, once you're satisfied that the UI is up-to-date, you should call `revalidate` followed by `repaint` on the container you changed. Because of the way the layout management works, the container hierarchy will also be updated

> one problem. If I keep use a button it keeps re-add buttons on the top panel which I don't want. how to solve that?

You really should be referencing the JavaDocs more, a quick scan through the [`JPanel` docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) would have highlighted the [`removeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#removeAll--) method

Answer (score 0):

Thanks MadProgrammer, Your answer was specific and linear. really liked it. Here is the full source code. People may come here to copy paste :D

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import static javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE;

public class Layout extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

Container container;
JPanel subPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel panelBottom = new JPanel();
FlowLayout flowLayout;

JPanel panelTop = new JPanel();
private static JButton b[] = new JButton[12];
JButton layoutButton[] = new JButton[3];
private static String sLayout[] = {"FlowLayout", "BorderLayout", "GridLayout"};
private static String s[] = {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12"};
String Screen = "";

public Layout() {
    super("Layout");
    container = getContentPane();

    panelTop.setLayout(new BorderLayout(3, 4));
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        b[i] = new JButton("Button " + s[i]);

        subPanel.add(b[i]);
    }
    panelTop.add(subPanel);
    container.add(panelTop, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    for (int i = 0; i < sLayout.length; i++) {
        layoutButton[i] = new JButton(sLayout[i]);
        layoutButton[i].addActionListener(this);
        panelBottom.add(layoutButton[i]);
    }
    container.add(panelBottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

}//End Constructor

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    if (event.getSource() == layoutButton[2]) {//gridLayout
        panelTop.removeAll();
        panelTop.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 4, 5, 15));
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            b[i] = new JButton("Button " + s[i]);

            panelTop.add(b[i]);
        }

        container.add(panelTop, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }
    if (event.getSource() == layoutButton[0]) {//flowLayout
        panelTop.removeAll();
        subPanel.removeAll();
        flowLayout = new FlowLayout();
        panelTop.setLayout(flowLayout);

        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            b[i] = new JButton("Button " + s[i]);

            subPanel.add(b[i]);
        }
        flowLayout.setAlignment(FlowLayout.LEFT);
        flowLayout.layoutContainer(container);
        panelTop.add(subPanel);
        container.add(panelTop, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }
    if (event.getSource() == layoutButton[1]) {//BorderLayout
        panelTop.removeAll();
        subPanel.removeAll();
        panelTop.setLayout(new BorderLayout(3, 4));
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            b[i] = new JButton("Button " + s[i]);

            subPanel.add(b[i]);
        }
        panelTop.add(subPanel);
        container.add(panelTop, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        revalidate();
        repaint();
      }
  }

}//end class

class LayoutTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Layout calculator = new Layout();
    calculator.setSize(900, 500);
    calculator.setVisible(true);
    calculator.setResizable(true);
    calculator.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    calculator.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   }
 }
```

Comment: You should not encourage people to copy paste.